# Use If inside a Select - Where

Tags: if-statement, select, plsql, where-clause

I was wondering: Is it possible to use an IF statement inside a WHERE clause for a SELECT? 
 Here's a sample:

```
SELECT var1, var2, .. AS name
FROM table1 C, table2 F, table3 D,.. 
WHERE C.id = f.id, AND ..
AND (IF expression THEN F.num <0; -- <-- is this possible?
     ELSE F.num >0);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `decode` inpalce of `IF`.

Answer (score 1):

IN THIS SCENARIO:  USE **CASE** STATMENT

```
SELECT var1, var2, .. AS name
FROM table1 C, table2 F, table3 D,.. 
WHERE C.id = f.id, AND ..
AND COL = (CASE WHEN F.NUM <0 THEN (UR COL) 
                WHEN ELSE F.num > 0 ELSE '' END)
```

Above Code is only Sample, Try to apply your own scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way. here's the solution

```
SELECT
.
.
WHERE ..
AND SIGN(F.NUM) = DECODE(expression,-1,1);
```

Simpler than I thought. Sorry for the trouble

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do without if statement.

```
Where (expression And num >0)
       Or ( not( expression) and num<0)
```